# Need help to remove JQuery dialog footer space

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery library 1.11 in our ASP.NET Web Application , but it is displaying unwanted space on footer on modal dialog. I am able to hide Title bar but not Footer space :(

Below is the HTML and script  for display Model.

HTML:

```
<div id="forgotPasswordOverlay" class="modalDialog">
  <div class="modalDialog-title">
    <h4>Forgot Password?</h4>
    <a href="#nogo" class="modalDialog-close">Close</a>
  </div>
  <div class="modalDialog-body">
    <p>
      Please contact your Company Administrator to reset your password if you continue having problems 
        logging in. Your Company Administrator is the only individual able to reset your password.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modalDialog-footer">
    <input id="btnClose" type="button" value="Close" class="submit-button modalDialog-close" />
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $("a#forgotPassword").on('click', function(e) {
    $( "#forgotPasswordOverlay" ).dialog({modal:true, width:520, closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) { 
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog || ui).hide();
     $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();   
     $(".ui-dialog-footer").hide();      

              attachOverlay('#forgotPasswordOverlay', {
            load: false
            });
    }});

      $("#btnClose").live('click', function(e) {
            $("#forgotPasswordOverlay").dialog("close");
        });

         $(".modalDialog-close").live('click', function(e) {        
            $("#forgotPasswordOverlay").dialog("close");
        });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: please post your html too

Comment: jquery is a library it wont be adding any footer space by itself. Can you create a jsfiddle of your code

Comment: will you please create one fiddle? or show screen shot of what you want to hide...

Comment: I think you just want to show information in dialog. you can use default setting of jquery ui dialog to do this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default @sukesh17

Comment: I am just trying to remove "ui-dialog-buttonpane" space from jquery modal dialog. But it is not hiding it. please tell me .. how to hide this space..!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are wanting to do is suppress the button area, which is at the foot or footer of the dialog window.  If this is correct then the following should hid it for you.

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").hide();
```

Comment: I am unable to hide footer - even using $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").hide(); Please provide me any other way...actually I am unable to upload image...since there is restriction to have 10-reputations. I am newly create account...Thanks.

Comment: FIXED ISSUE: $(#forgotPasswordOverlay".dialog({modal:true,draggable: true, resizable:false, width:520, closeOnEscape: false,open: function(event, ui) {$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog || ui).hide();$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide(); $(".ui-dialog- buttonpane", ui.dialog  ||ui).hide();$('#forgotPasswordOverlay').siblings('.ui-dialog-uttonpane').hide();}}); <style>.ui-dialog-titlebar-close{display: none;}.ui-widget-content {border:none}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content { padding: 0; margin:0 0 0 0; display:none;}.ui-widget-content { color: #776e65; border:none}</style>

Answer (score 0):

Providing the answer that @sukesh17 provided in a comment, as an answer for formatting and readability.

JS:

```
$("#forgotPasswordOverlay").dialog({
  modal:true,
  draggable: true, 
  resizable:false, 
  width:520, 
  closeOnEscape: false,
  open: function(event, ui) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog || ui).hide();
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide(); 
    $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane", ui.dialog || ui).hide();
    $('#forgotPasswordOverlay').siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').hide()‌​;
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
<style>
  .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none; }
  .ui-widget-content { border:none; }
  .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content { 
    padding: 0;
    margin:0; 
    display:none;
   }
   .ui-widget-content { 
     color: #776e65; 
     border:none;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery 1.10, the `ui` param on the `open` option is empty, and provided only for consistency with other event options. Therefore, you can not rely on it. I'm not sure about jQuery 1.11.

To hide the title bar and button pane, target the `.ui-dialog-titlebar` and `.ui-dialog-buttonpane` classes and hide them.

Additionally, if you are going to hide the title bar and button pane, don't forget to give your users a way of escaping out of the dialog. This might be an issue if your widget content is a menu, which will never get focus.

Also, make sure you provide a placeholder for the buttons, or the `.ui-dialog-buttonpane` div will never get created.

```
var closeText = "Close";
$("#forgotPasswordOverlay").dialog({
  modal:true,
  draggable: true, 
  resizable:false, 
  width:520, 
  closeOnEscape: false,
  buttons: [{ 
    text: closeText, 
    click: function () { 
      $("#forgotPasswordOverlay").dialog("close"); 
    } 
  }],
  open: function(event, ui) {
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").on("click", function () {
      $("#forgotPasswordOverlay").dialog("close");
    });
    $('#forgotPasswordOverlay .ui-dialog-titlebar').hide()‌​;
    $('#forgotPasswordOverlay .ui-dialog-buttonpane').hide()‌​;
  }
});
```

As commentary on the original JS, it would probably be a good idea to create the dialog first, hide it, then on click, just show it, rather than create it every time there is a click.

If your widget content was a menu, then additional CSS could be used to hide the extra padding and dialog border:

```
#forgotPasswordOverlay {
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#forgotPasswordOverlay > .ui-dialog-content {
  padding: 0;
}
```